# dealing with the missing value when using C4.5 technique

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, c4.5

I'm trying to build a classifier "model" using some classification techniques. Beginning with the C4.5 technique, faced the problem of missing values so:

How to deal with the missing values exist in a data-set ?

Should I have to stay on "?" in the missing attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of dealing with missing values:

1. *Get missing data:* If possible, try to acquire missing values.
2. *Discard missing data:*  Reduce the data available to a dataset having no missing values by discarding all instances with missing values or features.
3. *Imputation:* A better strategy is to impute the missing values, i.e., to infer them from the known part of the data. A common approach is to use the mean, the median or the most frequent value of the row or column in which the missing values are located. It is recommended to use multiple imputations.

This might help: http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume8/saar-tsechansky07a/saar-tsechansky07a.pdf